# Why does $\hat{\boldsymbol e_i} = \frac{\frac{\partial\mathbf r}{\partial q_i}}{\left\lvert\frac{\partial\mathbf r}{\partial q_i}\right\rvert}$?

Tags: multivariable-calculus, spherical-coordinates

So I'm trying to understand the derivation for the line element in spherical coordinates as well as the derivation for the basis vectors. Both hinge on the question posed in the title. So here's what I have so far in figuring this out:

In general, $\mathrm d\mathbf r = \frac{\partial\mathbf r}{\partial r}\mathrm dr+\frac{\partial\mathbf r}{\partial\theta}\mathrm d\theta+\frac{\partial\mathbf r}{\partial\varphi}\mathrm d\varphi$, but if we make $\mathrm d\theta=\mathrm d\varphi=0$ then the equation becomes $\mathrm d\mathbf r = \frac{\partial\mathbf r}{\partial r}\mathrm dr$, and also $\mathrm d\mathbf r$ points in the $\hat{\boldsymbol r}$ direction, since there is no change in the $\theta$ or $\varphi$ directions of the infinitessimal displacement. The next step would be to make the infinitesimal displacement a unit vector, and we accomplish this by diving by the magnitude. And here's where I'm getting stuck. I feel like the magnitude of the infintessimal displacement *should* be $\left\lvert\frac{\partial\mathbf r}{\partial r}\mathrm dr\right\rvert$ since $\mathrm d\mathbf r = \frac{\partial\mathbf r}{\partial r}\mathrm dr$, but of course the book is writing the magnitude simply as $\left\lvert\frac{\partial\mathbf r}{\partial r}\right\rvert$. What am I missing here?

Comment: You changed your title, and now in the body of the question there is no $e_i$.

Comment: @PNDas yes, I wanted to reflect the fact that I'm trying to derive the equation for all three coordinates, and I didn't have space to write them separately. $\hat{\mathbf e_1} = \hat{\boldsymbol r}$ etc.

Comment: The terms $\partial e_i$ in your title should be replaced by $\partial q_i$, where $q_i$ are generalized spatial coordinates.

Comment: Your question is phrased ambiguously (and probably by the guidelines of the site should be split up into two separate questions) but I can give you intuition for the more general statement. Any coordinate system will have a surface of constants for each variable, $r=k$, etc. Given a position in space, the rate of change of that position with respect to those variables is always orthogonal to these surfaces, and this is what defines the $\mathbf{e}_i$ vector directions. Of course there is nothing that guarantees that the speed at which these occur is unit speed, so a normalization is necessary.

Comment: @WilliamBarnes thanks! i updated it

Comment: @NinadMunshi yeah, i get the reasoning behind why it needs to be normalized, but I'm trying to figure why why the magnitude is doesn't include the $dr$ term. The reason I'm trying to find that out of to understand the derivation process for the unit vectors and the line element. The second paragraph in the body text is more or less me showing my work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Okay, that was a stupid question, and the answer was staring me in the face the whole time. If $\frac{\partial\mathbf r}{\partial\mathrm r}\mathrm dr$ points in the same direction as $\hat{\boldsymbol r}$ then so does $\frac{\partial\mathbf r}{\partial\mathrm r}$ and therefore $\hat{\boldsymbol r}=\frac{\frac{\partial\mathbf r}{\partial\mathrm r}\mathrm dr}{\left\lvert\frac{\partial\mathbf r}{\partial\mathrm r}\mathrm dr\right\rvert}=\frac{\frac{\partial\mathbf r}{\partial\mathrm r}}{\left\lvert\frac{\partial\mathbf r}{\partial\mathrm r}\right\rvert}$.